# java copying all contents of one file to another using input to read/create the file name

Tags: java, input, file-io, output, java.util.scanner

I'm having trouble using input to create the file that I want to write the lines from another file in. When my code reaches the file name I want to create, it doesn't let me input anything after I inputted the filename for file I want to open. I thought that this had something to do with the scanner not being able to take in the last "\n" or something so I tried to "flush" it with sc.nextLine() after the first time I called it but it didn't work. I don't really understand the logic of the system not working for the second nextLine(), shouldn't it be the same as the first one? Can someone explain please?

```
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter the file name to open with extension: ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            File file = new File(sc.nextLine());
            sc = new Scanner(file); //opens inputted file name
//          System.err.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

            System.out.println("What is the file name you want to create? ");
//          sc.nextLine();
            File write = new File(sc.nextLine());

            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(write);
//          System.out.println("Copying file contents over... ");
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                writer.println(line);
            }
            writer.close();
            sc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the file name to open with extension: ");

        File file = new File(br.readLine());
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file); //opens inputted file name

        System.out.println("What is the file name you want to create? ");
        File write = new File(br.readLine());

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(write);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            writer.println(line);
        }
        writer.close();
        sc.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```